# How do I say "like a bull in a china shop"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Searching, I found [this page](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/latin-word-for-817ca0e0f40498c5cde941cf838ba3cb6b38615f.html), which says "de armento in Sinis tabernam", which sounds to me like a (bad) literal word for word translation.

How can I express the feelings behind the English phrase, in Latin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing Latin idiom with the same meaning, so I'll translate instead.
The offered translation is nonsense; it has a cow, a shop, and China (the country!) but the syntax makes no sense.

Let me start with vocabulary:

- The typical word for a bull is *bos*.
- *Figlina* means a potter's workshop or a pottery.
  See [L&S for more meanings](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DF%3Aentry+group%3D14%3Aentry%3Dfiglinus); this is a form of the adjective *figlinus*, "pottery-related".

These were both well known concepts to the Romans.
Using elephants and Chinese imports (as some variants of the saying do) would make the Latin feel a little less natural.

With these, I'd phrase the idea as:

> *Sicut bos in figlina.*
> Like a bull in a pottery shop.